# Gravity Forms gform_after_submission & LDAP/Active Directory

Tags: php, wordpress, active-directory, ldap, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm new to Gravity/Wordpress/PHP - BUT here's what I'm after.

1. I have Gravity page that asks for username/password.
2. I'm using this Active Directory Integration Plugin (completely
   separate from GF) https://wordpress.org/plugins/active-directory-integration/

The ADI plugin works as expected with the default WP login screen, ie I enter LDAP creds it auth's against my ldap server confirms everything is good and lets me in.

Problem being I don't want to use the default wordpress login. Is there a way to use the GF and the after submission function to call this other plugin/php file to auth against ldap and or check the local WP db should the user not be found in AD?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325836/gform-after-submission-post-to-third-party-api

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement a function that is triggered by the `gform_after_submission`-action which then in turn calls the `authenticate`-action. But I'm not sure that will work...

But as far as I understand your question you want to replace/customize the login screen to something different. If that's the case you might want to have a look for 2 things:

1. A way to adapt the login-screen to your needs. Have a look at f.i. https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/customize-login-page/. I did a search in my favourite search engine for "customize wordpress login form"
2. replace the login URL with something different. For that you might want to have a look at the [iThemes-Security-plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-wp-security/) for wordpress which - amongst other excelent security features - allows you to rewrite the login-url to something other than `wp-login`. It does so in a completely transparent manner that you will have no problems updating your wordpress!

With these two changes you would be able to completely alter the existing login-screen to something individual without having to tweak the authentication mechanisms of wordpress which might result in strange (and insecure as the default login will still be available) behaviour.

Comment: Yes I've looked at that exact site - the problem with making those modifications is that it doesn't easily allow for wp updates without overwriting. So that really only leaves the plugin route.

Comment: The site describes how to change the loginscreen inside a cudtom theme  So you would either extend your current cudtom theme OR create your own custom theme as child-theme of your current theme which then only contains the adaptions for your login screen. That allows updating your complete wordpress-installation without having to worry as you will only adapt your own custom theme.